# How to embed dailymotion player in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

how can i embed dailymotion videos in windows phone ? Any SDK available for windows phone ? i'm searching on dailymotion website but nothing found.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an not an sdk that works with windows phone but there are a web service you can call to get info from

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api

Comment: half of my problem is solve now i can view uploaded videos only but how can i view live streaming in windows phone ?